# Could tag badges be made trackable in the badges tab at profile page?

Tags: feature-request, status-deferred, badges, tag-badges

Can we add the tag badges, eg to our "track the next badge as well"?

I know it's technically possible to track it, if you choose not to track your next privillege:

[image]

but it would be nice, if we could track them inside the badge progress tab as well:

[image]

[image]

Comment: It should be the minimum of the two fractions. Average is wrong, but used for sorting tags in the next tag selection box: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314537/ordering-for-next-tag-badge-options

Comment: We’ve reviewed this request and have moved it to our backlog. I’ve updated the status to [status-deferred].